# Adding 'lang' attribute to language links in template.php

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am not a Drupal developer, but still I would like to know how to make the links in a language switcher HTML5 valid. It seems these links lack an attribute 'lang' (with as value the abbrevation of the language). How would I do that in template.php?

Comment: Drupal 7 or Drupal 8? For Drupal 7, you could do a few things, but I might consider using MYTHEME_preprocess_link(&$variables) and adding the necessary attributes there ($variables['options']['attributes']). But it kind of depends on how these links are being created to identify which preprocess function would be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
function MYTHEME_links__locale_block(&$vars) {

  foreach($vars['links'] as $language => $langInfo) {
    $name = $langInfo['language']->native;
    $lang = $langInfo['language']->language;
    $vars['links'][$language]['title'] = $name;
    $vars['links'][$language]['attributes']['xml:lang'] = $lang;
    $vars['links'][$language]['attributes']['lang'] = $lang;
    $vars['links'][$language]['html'] = TRUE;
  }
  $content = theme_links($vars);
 return $content;
}
```